# getServerSideProps in next 13.4.19 returns undefined in page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I wanna fetch my data from a server side component. but when I try console.log it returns 'undefined'
I'm using json.server and its running well.

I have created an api path to fetch data and send it to front.
and I have created a getServerSideProps function in my page.tsx (homepage)

I have checked everything, from console.logging and all.
as much as I discovered , its the api path, when I wanted to go to localhost:3000/api/products : ' it returns 404 not found' and it shows this error in my terminal:

```
Warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider. This is currently unsupported.
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (J:\programmer apps\pixel-cart\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\adapters.js:84:11)
    at AppContainer (J:\programmer apps\pixel-cart\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:323:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (J:\programmer apps\pixel-cart\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:359:57)
    at div
    at Body (J:\programmer apps\pixel-cart\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:659:21)
```

**here is my folder structure: **

```
-app
   -api
       -products.ts
   -page.tsx
   -_app.tsx
```

**here is my app>api>products :**

the types are correct, the path is also working well

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { ProductProps } from '@/types';
import axios from 'axios';

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest, 
  res: NextApiResponse
  ) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products');
    const products: ProductProps[] = response.data;

    res.status(200).json(products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching data' });
  }
}
```

**the app>page file**

first it was a try()catch() in my getServerSideProps and then I removed it. I tried removing respons.data and instead used response .

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { BannerAds, BestSellers, GalleryItem, InputArrow, ProductCard } from '@/components'
import axios from 'axios';
import { ProductProps } from '@/types';

interface Props {
  products: ProductProps[]
}


export default function Home({products}: Props) {

  console.log(products)

  return (
    <main>
     
    </main>
  )}


  
export async function getServerSideProps () {
  
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products');
    const products = response.data;

    console.log(products);

    return {
      props: {
        products,
      },
    };
}
```

**and at last here is my _app.tsx**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

when I wanna map through it or I console.log it, it returns undefined

Comment: Are you using the `app` or `pages` router in Next.js?

Comment: The way your code is written you should put that into the pages directory. This could would need to be modified to work within the app directory.